# Recursively watch entire file system?

Tags: linux, search-indexing, inotify

For a software project I need to watch file system events* of entire filesystems on linux, each of which easily consists of more than 200.000 directories. How can I achieve this? (I already got it working on Windows)

From what I gather:

- **inotify** cannot watch recursively, and exhaustively watching every subdirectory is infeasible,
- **fanotify** does not notify deletions, renames and moves.

For what it's worth, I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, am root, and the filesystems are all local (no LAN/CIFS/etc).

No OS modifications — a user should be able to download the software and run it.

<sub>* create, delete, modify, move**.

** Instead of move, I can work with modify on the containing directories or delete/add.</sub>

Comment: Idea: Use `ftrace` or another [kernel tracing tool](http://elinux.org/Kernel_Trace_Systems) to capture all calls into the file system layer you are interested in.

Comment: Consider creating LSM module. It might be slightly less painful than writing full filesystem, and result in less context-switching, compared to something like FUSE.

Comment: I'm afraid build-time kernel 'modules' are not an option.